# How to increment the value of edittext for each row in a recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am developing a shopping cart and I want to increase the number of Items purchased when a user clicks a button in each row of the recyclerview.

I have tried to increment the edit text when a user clicks the increase button but it updates value of all edittext in the recyclerview.

**XML**

```
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:id="@+id/add"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:text="Add"
                    android:textColor="#FFF" />
                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:id="@+id/decrease"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="-"
                    android:textColor="#FFF" />
                <EditText
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:id="@+id/numberOfItems"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/add"
                    android:inputType="phone" />
                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/increase"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/numberOfItems"
                    android:text="+"
                    android:textColor="#FFF" />
                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/remove"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#dc3434"
                    android:text="Remove"
                    android:textColor="#FFF" />


            </LinearLayout>
```

**adapter**

```
public class BreadAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BreadAdapter.ViewHolder> {

public List<BreadModel> breads;
Context context;
private int quntity= 0;


public BreadAdapter(List<BreadModel> breads, Context context) {
    this.breads = breads;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public BreadAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_bread_recyclerview, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final BreadAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final BreadModel bread_title = breads.get(position);
    holder.tv_title.setText(bread_title.getName());
    holder.tv_price.setText(String.valueOf(bread_title.getPrice()));
    Log.i("info", bread_title.getImg());
    GlideApp.with(context)
            .load(bread_title.getImg())

    holder.increase.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            quntity= quntity+ 1;
            holder.et_numberOfItems.setText(String.valueOf(quntity));

        }
    });

}
public void update(){
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return breads.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private final EditText et_numberOfItems;
    TextView tv_title;
    TextView tv_price;
    ImageView img_breads;
    CardView cv_bread;
    AppCompatButton add;
    AppCompatButton remove;
    AppCompatButton increase;
    AppCompatButton decrease;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        et_numberOfItems = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.numberOfItems);
        tv_title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
        tv_price = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_price);
        img_breads = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.breadImageViews);
        cv_bread = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.breadCardView);
        add = (AppCompatButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.add);
        remove = (AppCompatButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.remove);
        increase = (AppCompatButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.increase);
        decrease = (AppCompatButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.decrease);
    }
}
}
```

Here is my adapter code please have look at it and help me thanks.

This is the screen shot
If I click on the plus(+) button it increases the number of item on all the edittext instead of that particular item

[image]

Comment: I didn't get your question you're updating edit text value how can change text views values? please share screen shots

Comment: BreadModel should have a quantity attribute, a field variable is always a field, wont change from method scope to class scope at convinience

Comment: I dont understand your statement @cutiko

Comment: quantity is a field which make it tobe equals for everytime the onBindViewholder method is called, that is why every BreaModel single instance should have their own counter inside of the BreadModel.class file